# Is there something similar to contains in netlogo

Tags: string, if-statement, netlogo

Im trying to do an if statement with an condition that if the string contains a certain word like bellow
    if(phrase) = "word")
Any ideas?

Comment: BTW: im using an extension called re (regular expressions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NetLogo's [`member?`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#member) primitive will do exactly that:

```
if member? "word" phrase [ do-something ]
```

Comment: Thanks, weird how its called member

Comment: A frequent use of the primitive is to check if an agent is contained in an agent set. Talking about a "member" of a set is commonplace in math.